# Systemctl service timed out during start

Tags: server, bash, systemd, services

<I have created `*.service` and placed it in my `/etc/systemd/system` folder:

```
[Unit]
Description=WSO2 IoT Message broker

[Service]
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/wso2iot-3.1.0/bin/broker.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm tying to run one of mudles of WSO2 IoT Server, but it does not matter.

When I launch this `bash` script manually, it loads for a long time and keeps in launched mode, because it runs something like web server application which then takes specific port.

When I launch this service like this:

```
sudo systemctl start myservice.service
```

It takes a long time and then says: `Start operation timed out. Terminating.`

I need to make this service just launched forever until I stop it manually.

What did I miss in my service config file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `Type` of your service script either to `simple` or `oneshot`. Depending on the behavior of the shell script that is started.

- if the shell script runs an endless loop and does not exit, set `Type` to `simple`
- otherwise set `Type` to `oneshot`

After you have made your changes reload the configuration with `systemctl daemon-reload` and start your service.

Comment: can anyone explain why change Type from 'fork' to 'simple' fixed this issue?

Comment: I second @user1655072 request! `oneshot` is easy to understand; `simple` vs. `forking` is not. Why exactly does one work, but not the other?

Answer (score 3):

I also had to add (or was it because I rebooted in the end, and TimeoutSec actually doesn't make a difference?)

```
TimeoutSec=0
```

As described in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1446015#c7

The `man systemd.service` command on my own systems tells me `infinity` should be used for that. I guess both work.

Like so (Whatever GuessMainPID is, but this is how my currently working file looks like):

/etc/systemd/system/foo@.service

```
[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutSec=0
GuessMainPID=false
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "funny stuff %I"
```

My service was triggered from an udev rule (as in http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html), no Idea if that makes any difference. For anyone wondering how to get the timeout log: I had to run `journalctl | tail` to see which kinds of errors my udev rule and service just produced.